# How to write a templated function that accepts a std::optional or an arithmetic type and selects the correct underlying type

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a templated function that can take a `std::optional` or a arithmetic type as the argument. The function then needs to select the underlying type and convert a string to the underlying arithmetic type or the arithmetic type.

```
#include <optional>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename F = std::conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>,
                                                       T,
                                                       typename T::value_type>>
void convertNumericColumn(std::string &column, T &value)
{
  if (!column.empty())
  {
    try
    {
//      value = boost::lexical_cast<F>(column); // Only commented out to ensure the code compiles.
    }
    catch(...){}
  };
}

int  main(int, char **)
{
  std::string value = "123";

  std::optional<std::uint64_t> test1;
  std::uint64_t test2;

  convertNumericColumn(value, test1); // Compile OK
  convertNumericColumn(value, test2); // Does not compile.
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9vfsK1oqr

The errors are
error: no matching function for call to 'convertNumericColumn(std::string&, uint64_t&)'
and
error: 'long unsigned int' is not a class, struct, or union type

Comment: wouldn't the optional part of the optional be the arithmetic type?  Just put it in an optional.  Are you just trying to save typing?  That's infrequently a good way to code -- increasing complexity to save typing makes your code harder to maintain long term.

Comment: There is more to the function than displayed in the example above. The string may also be empty in some cases. I also edited the comments in the code to indicate that the lexical_cast was only commented out to ensure the code compiles.

Comment: What error do you get during compilation?

Comment: > No matching function for call to convertNumericColumn. and long unsigned int is not a class struct or union type

Comment: The problem is that you are using std::conditional_t and passing T which doesn't have value_type. long unsigned int doesn't have value_type, so the compilation fails. T must have a value type as per your code else it fails with the error you get.

Comment: The full error messages should contain more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `std::conditional_t` and passing `T` which doesn't have `value_type` i.e. `long unsigned int` doesn't have `value_type`, so the compilation fails. `T` must have a `value_type` as per your code else it fails with the error you get.

Instead you can use `if constexpr` like this:

```
#include <optional>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template<typename T>
void convertNumericColumn(std::string &column, T &value)
{
    if (!column.empty())
    {
        try
        {
            if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
            {
                value = boost::lexical_cast<T>(column);    
            }
            else
            {
                value = boost::lexical_cast<typename T::value_type>(column);
            }
        }
        catch(...){}
    };
}
int  main(int, char **)
{
  std::string value = "123";

  std::optional<std::uint64_t> test1;
  std::uint64_t test2;

  convertNumericColumn(value, test1);
  convertNumericColumn(value, test2);
  std::cout << test1.value() << ' ' << test2 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both the second and third template arguments to `std::conditional` should be valid which isn't the case when `T` doesn't have a `value_type`.

One way to solve this is to write your own trait to check for the conditions and then use SFINAE as shown below.

```
template<class T>
struct is_ok {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>; 
};

template<class T>
struct is_ok<std::optional<T>> {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;  
};
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_ok_v = is_ok<T>::value;     
 
template<typename T>     
typename std::enable_if_t<is_ok_v<T>> convertNumericColumn(std::string &column, T &value)
{   
  if (!column.empty())  
  {
    try 
    {
//      value = boost::lexical_cast<F>(column); // Only commented out to ensure the code compiles.
    }
    catch(...){}
  };
}
int main()
{
  std::string value = "123";

  std::optional<std::uint64_t> test1;
  std::uint64_t test2;

  convertNumericColumn(value, test1); // Compile OK
  convertNumericColumn(value, test2); // Works now
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s3oErjsYd)

Answer (score 0):

Here is two solutions for your problmen statement.

The first one is an alternative to your approach (which uses [in/out] argument to the conversion function), the second approach is IMO much easier. Have a look at both

---

```
    #include <optional>
    #include <type_traits>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    
    namespace traits
    {
        // determine if a type is an optional type
    
        template <typename type_t, typename = void>
        constexpr bool is_optional_t_v = false;
    
        template <typename type_t>
        constexpr bool is_optional_t_v<type_t, std::void_t<std::optional<typename type_t::value_type>>> = true;
    }
    
    namespace boost
    {
        // poor man's cast for local testig
        template<typename type_t>
        constexpr auto lexical_cast(const std::string& input) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<type_t>, type_t>
        {
            type_t retval = std::stoi(input);
            return retval;
        }
    }
    
    // handle the arithmetic case
    template<typename type_t>
    auto convert(const std::string& input, type_t& value) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<type_t>, void>
    {
        auto converted_value = boost::lexical_cast<type_t>(input);
        std::cout << "arithmetic type handled, value = " << converted_value << "\n";
        value = converted_value;
    }
    
    // handle the optional arithmetic case
    template<typename type_t>
    auto convert(const std::string& input, type_t& value) -> 
        std::enable_if_t
        <
            traits::is_optional_t_v<type_t> && 
            std::is_arithmetic_v<typename type_t::value_type
        >, void>
    {
        auto converted_value = boost::lexical_cast<typename type_t::value_type>(input);
        std::cout << "std::optional type handled, value = " << converted_value << "\n";
        value = converted_value;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        static_assert(!traits::is_optional_t_v<int>);
        static_assert(traits::is_optional_t_v<std::optional<int>>);
        static_assert(traits::is_optional_t_v<std::optional<std::string>>);
    
        std::string input{"123"};
    
        int value{ 1 };
        convert(input, value);
    
        std::optional<int> optional_value{1};
        convert(input, optional_value);
    
        std::optional<std::string> optional_string{"hello"};
        //auto result3 = convert(input, optional_string); <== does not compile since the optional is not arithemtic
    
        return 0;
    }
```

---

The second more simple approach :

```
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace boost
{
    // poor man's cast for local testig
    template<typename type_t>
    constexpr auto lexical_cast(const std::string& input) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<type_t>, type_t>
    {
        type_t retval = std::stoi(input);
        return retval;
    }
}

template<typename type_t>
type_t convertNumericColumn(const std::string &column)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<type_t>(column);
}

int main()
{
  std::string value = "123";
  std::optional<std::uint64_t> test1;
  std::uint64_t test2;

  
  // optional knows what to do with a uint64_t assignment
  // no need to write more complex code than this
  test1 = convertNumericColumn<std::uint64_t>(value);
  test2 = convertNumericColumn<std::uint64_t>(value); 

  std::cout << *test1 << ' ' << test2 << '\n';
}
```